# Can someone get his previous credits counted in a new Master's programme in the EU?

Tags: graduate-school, accreditation, eu

Suppose, someone studied in a 120ECTS MSc program in CS in a country 'X' in the EU. He obtained 60 ECTS there, but he also has some failed courses. He then abandons the program.

Now, he moves to a country 'Y' in the EU and gets admission to program CS in the country 'Y' after 5 years.

Can he get his 60 ECTS credits counted by the school offering CS?

Comment: Does "graduate" mean "PhD"? There is no such thing in Europe, mostly (in the sense of having to take courses, get ECTS points, etc.). Or do you mean Master studies.

Comment: Is this you? It's much easier to read in first person, IMO

Comment: 5 years is a long time. I believe in quite a few programs you get kicked out after less years if you don't make enough progress. I doubt such old credits would be counted.

Answer (score 0):

They will decide what credits / courses they will be prepared to accept.

All you can do is show what you have covered so far, even including syllabi may help make a case but, remember they get to decide what is accepted.

Comment: If the question is "does X work", "You have to check if X works" is not an answer. It is the question.

Comment: @user151413 Seems perfectly reasonable as an answer to me, this is basically the "it's up to your program" answer. It's a question that has to be asked of the specific program, no general answer can be given here.

Comment: @BryanKrause So you are saying the question should be closed.

Comment: @user151413 Indeed, that's how I voted.

Comment: If the only possible answer is "It depends on individual circumstances", then the question should be closed.

Comment: @BrianBorchers ... rather than answered.

Comment: @SolarMike Oh. I did. And I stick to my conviction.